# Why rebuild module does not recompile dependency module, but build module does in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, dependencies, rebuild

I have created my own Arrays class with toString method in Ders4Lib module. I added this module as dependency to the Ders4 module (I used module dependency). Now when I change something in Ders4Lib module and rebuild module Ders4 I get error, because it compiles direclty Ders4 and do not see changes. When I firstly rebuild Ders4Lib and then rebuild Ders4 it is working. But when I use build module (not rebuild) I did not get error, because it compiles Ders4Lib module and then Ders4 module. Is that bug or if it is not why this is happening?
[Ders4 module settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3De8.png)
[I changed toString method name to toString2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7poN9.png)

I try to use rebuild module and get error. I expected it to work either with rebuild module or build module. With build module it is working.

Comment: Are you sure that running build on Ders4 also builds  Ders4Lib? Probably it builds (incrementally) the main module and uses cached data for Lib module. Is it possible to share project sample for investigation?

Comment: @y.bedrov, https://github.com/kamranbaxshaliyev/myfirstproject